# Convert.ChangeType and converting to enums?

Tags: c#, enums, changetype

I got an `Int16` value, from the database, and need to convert this to an enum type. This is unfortunately done in a layer of the code that knows very little about the objects except for what it can gather through reflection.

As such, it ends up calling `Convert.ChangeType` which fails with an invalid cast exception.

I found what I consider a smelly workaround, like this:

```
String name = Enum.GetName(destinationType, value);
Object enumValue = Enum.Parse(destinationType, name, false);
```

Is there a better way, so that I don't have to move through this String operation?

Here's a short, but complete, program that can be used if anyone need to experiment:

```
using System;

public class MyClass
{
    public enum DummyEnum
    {
        Value0,
        Value1
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Int16 value = 1;
        Type destinationType = typeof(DummyEnum);

        String name = Enum.GetName(destinationType, value);
        Object enumValue = Enum.Parse(destinationType, name, false);

        Console.WriteLine("" + value + " = " + enumValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch... I need to stop trying to answer questions like this before I've had my coffee...

Comment: I see now, the Console.WriteLine is also in a layer that does not have access to the enum type. I completely misunderstood. Deleted my (stupid) answer.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`Enum.ToObject(....` is what you're looking for!

**C#**

```
StringComparison enumValue = (StringComparison)Enum.ToObject(typeof(StringComparison), 5);
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim enumValue As StringComparison = CType([Enum].ToObject(GetType(StringComparison), 5), StringComparison)
```

If you do a lot of Enum converting try using the following class it will save you alot of code.

```
public class Enum<EnumType> where EnumType : struct, IConvertible
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves an array of the values of the constants in a specified enumeration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public static EnumType[] GetValues()
    {
        return (EnumType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public static EnumType Parse(string name)
    {
        return (EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), name);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="ignoreCase"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public static EnumType Parse(string name, bool ignoreCase)
    {
        return (EnumType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), name, ignoreCase);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the specified object with an integer value to an enumeration member.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public static EnumType ToObject(object value)
    {
        return (EnumType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(EnumType), value);
    }
}
```

Now instead of writing `(StringComparison)Enum.ToObject(typeof(StringComparison), 5);` you can simply write `Enum<StringComparison>.ToObject(5);`.

Comment: Legend!  Didn't know about this.  Isn't stackoverflow brill?! :-)

Comment: Been struggling for over an hour with a similar issue and this solved it! A well earned +1 even two years after posting it ;)

Comment: `ToObject()` appears to allow values that don't exist in the enum and also values outside the range of the underlying type: `Enum.ToObject(typeof(IntEnumType), (long)Int32.MaxValue + 1)`

Comment: @NelsonRothermel: C# itself allows enum values that aren't defined in the enum, so no surprise there.  Your other point is more accurate when compared to casting, but it seems to just be a special case of your first point (it seems to cast to the underlying type first?)

Comment: I saw this method a lot of times (in intellisense) but had know idea about its task. The designers could have given a more intuitive name to this method.

Comment: You can now use `public class Enum<EnumType> where EnumType : Enum` with C# 7.3 to further pin down the generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Peter's answer here is the method for `Nullable<int>` to `Enum` conversion:

```
public static class EnumUtils
{
        public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(int? value, out TEnum result)
            where TEnum: struct, IConvertible
        {
            if(!value.HasValue || !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), value)){
                result = default(TEnum);
                return false;
            }
            result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), value);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Using `EnumUtils.TryParse<YourEnumType>(someNumber, out result)` becomes useful for many scenarios. For example, WebApi Controller in Asp.NET does not have default protection against invalid Enum params. Asp.NET will just use `default(YourEnumType)` value, even if some passes `null`, `-1000`, `500000`, `"garbage string"` or totally ignores the parameter. Moreover, `ModelState` will be valid in all these cases, so one of the solution is to use `int?` type with custom check

```
public class MyApiController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(int? myEnumParam){    
        MyEnumType myEnumParamParsed;
        if(!EnumUtils.TryParse<MyEnumType>(myEnumParam, out myEnumParamParsed)){
            return BadRequest($"Error: parameter '{nameof(myEnumParam)}' is not specified or incorrect");
        }      

        return this.Get(washingServiceTypeParsed);            
    }
    private IActionResult Get(MyEnumType myEnumParam){ 
       // here we can guarantee that myEnumParam is valid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing an Enum in a DataTable but don't know which column is an enum and which is a string/int, you can access the value this way:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
    foreach (DataColumn dataCol in myDataTable.Columns)
    {
        object v = dataRow[dataCol];
        Type t = dataCol.DataType;
        bool e = false;
        if (t.IsEnum) e = true;

        Trace.WriteLine((dataCol.ColumnName + ":").PadRight(30) +
            (e ? Enum.ToObject(t, v) : v));
    }
}
```