# Error of Convert.ChangeType in conversion from "string" to "GSMModemTypeConstants"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, sms, gsm

```
comboBox2.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GSMModemTypeConstants));
GSMModemTypeConstants s_type = (GSMModemTypeConstants)Convert.ChangeType(
    comboBox2.Text, typeof(GSMModemTypeConstants));
```

In the first line the user select the type of his modem from a comboBox which gets the list of the modems available from the Enum GSMModemTypeConstants. In the second line I want to pass the selected modem type to s_type which will later be used by the method that actually sends the SMS.

When I manually set the s_type everything works perfect for example:

```
GSMModemTypeConstants s_type = GSMModemTypeConstants.gsmModemSonyEricsson;
// OR
GSMModemTypeConstants s_type = GSMModemTypeConstants.gsmModemNokia;
```

But when I try to retrieve the choice from the `comboBox` and set the `s_type` like I do in the second line the conversion gives me an error which I can't understand.

[image: the error]

Am I handling the `Convert.ChangeType` method wrong? If it's not my fault then is there any other way to convert a type from string to something else, other than `Convert.ChangeType`?

---

**Solution**
I still don't have the required reputation to answer it below, so here is the code...

```
GSMModemTypeConstants s_type = (GSMModemTypeConstants)System.Enum.Parse(
    typeof(GSMModemTypeConstants), comboBox2.Text);`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert.ChangeType and converting to enums?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507059/convert-changetype-and-converting-to-enums)

Comment: "Enum.ToObject()" instead of "Convert.ChangeType" in the line I get the error ?

Comment: If you have a solution to your own problem, please make it an answer so people in the future will find the answer faster. There is no rep restriction on making any answer. And please avoid using [solved] in your title.

Answer (score 1):

If `comboBox2.Text` has a number (integer) then you should first convert that value to `int` and then cast it to `GSMModemTypeConstants`, e.g.:

```
int modemType = int.Parse(comboBox2.Text));
GSMModemTypeConstants s_type = (GSMModemTypeConstants)modemType;
```

Or, convert `comboBox2.SelectedItem` to your enum.

Comment: it's a string actually, the enum contains contains a list of the modem models. I just found a solution to my problem, it was solved by Enum.Parse. Thank you anyway for your answer!