# Enum conversion/serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, enums

I'm writing a serializer class and I'm trying to write a function to be able to serialize any enum (could be backed by int, byte, ulong...). Will this work the way I want it to? Is there a better way to do it?

```
public bool Serialize<TEnum>(ref TEnum data, TEnum min, TEnum max) where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("arguments must be an Enum");
    }

    Type eType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(data.GetType());

    if (eType == typeof(byte) || eType == typeof(ushort) || eType == typeof(uint) || eType == typeof(ulong))
    {
        var data2 = (ulong) Convert.ChangeType(data, eType);
        var min2 = (ulong) Convert.ChangeType(min, eType);
        var max2 = (ulong) Convert.ChangeType(max, eType);

        if (IsReading)
        {
            bool success = bs.Read(out data2, min2, max2);
            data = (TEnum) Convert.ChangeType(data2, typeof(TEnum));
            return success;
        }
        bs.Write(data2, min2, max2);
    }
    else
    {
        var data2 = (long) Convert.ChangeType(data, eType);
        var min2 = (long) Convert.ChangeType(min, eType);
        var max2 = (long) Convert.ChangeType(max, eType);

        if (IsReading)
        {
            bool success = bs.Read(out data2, min2, max2);
            data = (TEnum) Convert.ChangeType(data2, typeof(TEnum));
            return success;
        }
        bs.Write(data2, min2, max2);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using one of the built-in serialisers, or failing that, something like JSON.NET?

Comment: better to put if code in separate function which will return Boolean and declare all the variable on top of the function instead in if and else because you are doing redundant thing , might me it help you too clean that code .
and you can also trying for third party packages
Hope, it will help Thanks

Comment: @MatthewWatson there is a reason, but it's not really relevant to the question. I'm trying to figure out generic enum conversion.

Comment: @PankajGupta I'm not really sure what you're saying. Could you show me some code, please? Yes, I'm doing redundant thing because I have to work with signed and unsigned integers.

Comment: @Tim , i need to check

Comment: Rather than `Convert.ChangeType()` I think you want `Enum.ToObject()`.  See [Convert.ChangeType and converting to enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507059/convert-changetype-and-converting-to-enums).  Hard to say beyond that without a [mcve].  What is `bs`?  What does `bs.Read(out data2, min2, max2);` do?

Comment: @dbc That's just reading an integer from a stream (bs is bitstream), same with write().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a `long` or `ulong` to an `enum` that is backed by a smaller type of integer, you need to use [`Enum.ToObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject.aspx).  `Convert.ChangeType()` will throw an exception if the underlying numeric types do not have the same number of bytes.  And [`IConvertible.ToInt64()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.toint64.aspx) or `IConvertible.ToUInt64()` will be slightly faster than `Convert.ChangeType()` since the latter actually calls the former.

Other than that, the following should work and serialize an enum as 8 bytes into a serialization stream.  For a non-`long` enum this will be less space-efficient than serializing it as its underlying numeric type, but has the advantage of allowing the underlying numeric type to be changed subsequently (e.g. from `int` to `long` to accommodate additional `[Flags]` values) without invalidating old serialization streams:

```
public static class SerializationExtensions
{
    static bool EnumTypeIsSigned(this Type tEnum)
    {
        var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(tEnum);
        if (underlyingType == typeof(long) || underlyingType == typeof(int) || underlyingType == typeof(short) || underlyingType == typeof(sbyte))
            return true;
        if (underlyingType == typeof(ulong) || underlyingType == typeof(uint) || underlyingType == typeof(ushort) || underlyingType == typeof(byte))
            return false;
        throw new ArgumentException(tEnum.Name + " is not an enum type");
    }

    static bool IsSigned<TEnum>(this TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        return typeof(TEnum).EnumTypeIsSigned();
    }

    public static void WriteEnum<TEnum>(this BinaryWriter writer, TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        if (value.IsSigned())
        {
            var underlyingValue = checked(value.ToInt64(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
            writer.Write(underlyingValue);
        }
        else
        {
            var underlyingValue = checked(value.ToUInt64(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
            writer.Write(underlyingValue);
        }
    }

    public static TEnum ReadEnum<TEnum>(this BinaryReader reader) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        if (typeof(TEnum).EnumTypeIsSigned())
        {
            var underlyingValue = reader.ReadInt64();
            return checked((TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), underlyingValue));
        }
        else
        {
            var underlyingValue = reader.ReadUInt64();
            return checked((TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), underlyingValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OoNn95).